# Function as dictionary keys, unhashable type

Tags: opengl, python-2.7, dictionary, function-pointers

I was trying to be really clever with openGL and store all of my functions and their variables in a dictionary in logical order, and then call them in functional order later.

```
def complex_draw_square(width, height, x=0, y=0, z=0, x_angle=0, y_angle=0, z_angle=0,):
    action_dict = {
        glPopMatrix: "E",
        glRectf: (0, 0, width, height),
        glTranslatef: (0, -height, 0),
        glRotatef: (x_angle, y_angle, z_angle, 1),
        glTranslatef: (x, y + height, z),
        glPushMatrix: "E"
    }
    return action_dict
```

The problem is, When I try to do this I get File

```
"/Users/lego90511/PycharmProjects/OpenGLDummy/opengl_shortcuts.py", line 9, in complex_draw_square
    glPopMatrix: "E",
TypeError: unhashable type
```

I get this no matter which function variable combination I have. The weird thing is that I try this in the terminal with a custom function

```
def sum(x,y):
     return x + y
d = {sum: (1, 2)}
for f in d.keys():
     print f(*d[f])
>>>3
```

And this worked. So why doesn't the other one work?

Comment: "store [...] in a dictionary in logical order". Dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: You do know that Python dictionaries *have no order*, right?

Comment: In the back of my head I did I guess it has something to deal with hashing conflicts, but for the sake of argument let's say no. dict.keys() still spit out the keys in the expected order will they not?

Comment: @EasilyBaffled: No, `dict.keys()` will spit out the keys in any order it pleases. `collections.OrderedDict` might be worth a look.

Comment: And of course you can't have duplicate keys (`glTranslatef` in your example).

Comment: @EasilyBaffled: The order of keys in a dictionary depends on the order of insertions and deletions of all it's keys since it was first created, as hash collisions can lead to keys being slotted in a different place. As such, dictionary order is arbitrary. It'll only remain stable as long as you don't add or remove keys.

Comment: As for the error: PyOpenGL functions are not the same kind of object as Python's built-in functions or functions you define in the interpreter. They are evidently missing at least one of two required pieces: hooks to generate a hash value and to test equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you expect the items to retain their order, and that you have duplicate keys (`glTranslatef` in your example), Python dictionaries are not a suitable data structure for this.

Why not use a list or a tuple instead:

```
actions = [
    (glPopMatrix, "E"),
    (glRectf, 0, 0, width, height),
    (glTranslatef, 0, -height, 0),
    (glRotatef, x_angle, y_angle, z_angle, 1),
    (glTranslatef, x, y + height, z),
    (glPushMatrix, "E")
]
```